# Principle argument for $-1-i=-\frac{3\pi}{4} \ne \frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I want to find the principle argument for $-1-i$

Using the standard method for finding $\theta=\arctan\left({\frac{y}{x}}\right)$

$$\arctan(\frac{-1}{-1})=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

But:

$$\operatorname{Arg}(-1-i)=-\frac{3\pi}{4}$$

But $\frac{\pi}{4}$ is within $-\pi\lt \Theta \leq \pi$, so why is my method for finding $\Theta$ wrong?

Comment: arctan doesn't understand quadrants. You have to keep track of this yourself.

Comment: What is the range of $\arctan x$?

Comment: Oh so we know it is in the third quadrant, so we say, $\frac{\pi}{4}$ clockwise into the 3rd

Comment: Or just think of adding or subtracting $\pi$

Comment: I personally prefer to give you that hint as answer, but deleted by mod. Now it is a comment. Whatever, you must know that the range of $\arctan x$ does not fit that of the angle you want. So you had better get a visual idea of your solution. This is what I was saying. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

For each $z\in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$, we denote by $\arg(z)\in(-\pi, \pi]$ the principal argument of $z=x+iy$ and $\arg(z)$ is deduced as follows:

$$\arg(z)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\pi/2 & \mbox{if}\: z=iy, y>0\\
-\pi/2 & \mbox{if}\: z=iy, y<0\\
\arctan{(y/x)}& \mbox{if}\:  x>0, y\geq 0\\
\arctan{(y/x)}+\pi& \mbox{if}\:  x<0, y\geq 0\\
\arctan{(y/x)}-\pi& \mbox{if}\:  x<0, y<0\\
\arctan{(y/x)}& \mbox{if}\:  x>0, y<0\end{array}\right.$$

Note that $\arctan:\mathbb{R}\to (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ is one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to find the argument for a complex number, we have to mind the quadrant since $\arctan$ will not do this for us. When $z = -1 - i$, we see that we are in the third quadrant. Let's find $\theta = \arctan(y/x) = \arctan(1) = \pi/4$. Since we know we should be in the third quadrant, we should be suspect of this as an answer. In order to to have the correct argument, we must add or subtract $\pi$. Since we are looking for the principal argument, we have $\theta = \arctan(1) - \pi = -3\pi/4\in(-\pi,\pi)$. The moral is that there was nothing wrong with your method but you lost track of the details and returned a wrong argument.